# How can i eliminate underlines on non-linked urls?

Tags: css, underline

I know outlook (word) adds  tags to links, and I know there are a few ways via CSS to override this (both in the style tags in the header, and in the a href).

But these tags are ignored, edited and/or just don't work.

In this case, outlook and aol mail clients seem to add an underline in a url that is NOT wrapped in an href.

Even if I apply a SPAN tag, and declare text-decoration: none, the underline shows up.

Any suggestions how to eliminate this?

Comment: If you have copied text from word best to paste in notepad as this strips the naff tags that word adds to it.

Comment: as for CSS styles have you added !important to the ones you want to use to see if that helps!

Comment: You can right-click on the link and select inspect element to see if the link received the attribute "text-decoration:none." Most likely it is applied to the span but not to the <a> tag that contains your link.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question -
In an email - outlook and aol ADD href tags to anything that starts with www and ends in .com - so there is no  href nor span tag in my email source code - intentionally - this is for a legal disclaimer , we don't want it to actually link but links are bing added

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question. Or maybe the question is misleading. As you say "In email - outlook and aol", which only means this is not a programming problem. But check this link. Hope it will help you. https://www.msoutlook.info/question/remove-underline-and-changing-hyperlinks-color

Answer (score 0):

```css
span{
text-decoration:none;
}
.link{
text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<span><a href="#" >LinkA</a></span>
<span><a class="link" href="#" >LinkB</a></span>
```

span tag does not apply text-decoration:none.
apply the style to the anchor tag instead.

Comment: in email - outlook and aol ADD href tags to anything that starts with www and ends in .com - so there is no (desired) href nor span tag

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520155/override-remove-underline-link-style-in-outlook